# How to provide GridPattern to custom control

Tags: c#, datagridview, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

We have a custom control which derives from `DataGridView`.

Now I want to write an automated test, which clicks on a row of this DataGridView.
I'm using **Microsoft UI Automation** for this.

Unfortunately, the `GridPattern` is not available, because it's a custom control...

How can I make this custom control testable with Microsoft UI Automation?

Do I have to implement `IGridProvider`? And if yes, how do I have to do this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744822(v=vs.110).aspx DataGridView will only be supported through microsoft active accessibility. So it looks like you would need to implement IGridProvider and IGridItemProvider.

These articals talk about implementing custom properties and providers in general

[Part 1 UIA-CustomPatterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/12/08/uia-custom-patterns-part-1.aspx)

[Part 2 UIA-CustomPatterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/12/08/uia-custom-patterns-part-2.aspx)

[Part 3 UIA-CustomPatterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/06/05/custom-ui-automation-providers-in-depth-part-3.aspx)

[Part 4 UIA-CustomPatterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/06/05/custom-ui-automation-providers-in-depth-part-4.aspx)

Then you would want to implement [IGridProvder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.igridprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and then implement [IGridItemProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.igriditemprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) for the items in the grid.